# z-index and <a href>

Tags: php, html, css

I have a sequence of 5 user images that I am stacking horizontally using a z-index. i.e: `<img src="xxxx" style="z-index:5;position:relative;">` and then z-index 4...3..etc.

I now want to link these images to the user's 'profile'. If I surround my `<img>` with an `<a>` it breaks the formatting. It just shows the images in a line (with the z-indexes still correct(!?)) instead of overlapped. I tried just `<a href="xx"><img></a>` and also `<a href="xx" style="position:relative"><img></a>` but nothing has worked.

```
    <?php $count = 5; ?>
<?php foreach($today_all_result as $today_all_results) : ?>          
    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URI; ?>/user/?user=<?php echo $today_all_results->user_id; ?>" style="position:relative;z-index:<?php echo $count; ?>">
        <img src='<?php echo BASE_URI; ?>/images/userImages/<?php echo $today_all_results->userPicture; ?>' class="pic-athlete <?php echo $stacked; ?>" style="z-index:<?php echo $count; ?>;position:relative;">
      </a>
       <?php $count--; ?>
       <?php $stacked = "stacked"; ?>
       <?php if($count <= 0) break; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: position the `a` elements, not the `img` elements.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add a jsFiddle or some code

Comment: adding on to what @zzzzBov said, you may need to add `display: block` to the `a`s

Comment: adding position to the a elements doesn't work. neither does adding z-index to them for some reason. adding display:block makes them vertically aligned.

Comment: @MoolsBytheway added code the orig question

Answer (score 0):

Change the style from `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;`

```css
img{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href="ddd"><img src="" style="background-color: blue; z-index: 10;"/></a>
<a href="ddd"><img src="" style="background-color: green; z-index: 2;"/></a>
<a href="ddd"><img src="" style="background-color: red; z-index: 3;"/></a>
```

Another example:

```css
img{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href="ddd"><img src="" style="background-color: blue; z-index: 1;"/></a>
<a href="ddd"><img src="" style="background-color: green; z-index: 2; left: 20px; top: 20px;"/></a>
<a href="ddd"><img src="" style="background-color: red; z-index: 3;left: 40px; top: 40px;"/></a>
```

Comment: doing this hides all the images underneath each other

Comment: This is what you asked for: "It just shows the images in a line instead of overlapped." If you want to partially overlap add the `left` and `top` attributes to each image.

Comment: for some reason this just shows me one image instead of all of them. like they overlap each other 100% instead of just partially

Comment: You didn't provide an example or explaine what you're expecting. I added an another example with partial overlapping